# What defines the curse type?

Tags: dominion

I am making a homebrew expansion to Dominion and I want to include some more curse-type cards. However, what does the curse type mean for a card? Does it mean - VP, or just something undesirable to have in your deck?

Comment: Dark Ages has two other types of cards which are also undesirable: Ruins and shelters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curse type is defined by nothing more and nothing less than having the word “Curse” on the card in the type line.

This is true of other types as well, such as “Attack”. Attack does not mean that the card hurts your opponent, it only means that it has the word “Attack” on the bottom. Mechanically and thematically though, it is better to only have Attack type on cards that hurt your opponent.

Certain types in Dominion, such as “Action”, do have special rules that come with them. But many other types have no rules. Curse has no special rules, the type doesn’t mean anything at all.

That being said, making another card with the type “Curse” is not good for a fan expansion. This is because “Curse” is both the name of a card and a type of card, and the only card with that type is the card named “Curse”. If another card with that type existed, then cards that said “gain a Curse” would be confusing and ambiguous... does “Gain a Curse” mean gain a card named Curse, or does it mean gain a card with the type Curse? There is no correct answer. That ambiguity is only ok because there is no other card with that type.

So, if you want a different card that will hurt players, whether by having negative VP or by clogging their deck, just leave off that type. You can see how Dark Ages did that thing by introducing Ruins.

Comment: It might be noted that the first edition witch says “each other player gains a curse _card_”.

Answer (score 2):

Curses are dead cards that do nothing but take up space in your deck and provide negative victory points.

If you look on the wiki at card types you will see that curse type cards are a special card type with only one card name for them.

[Wiki-Curse](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Curse)

[Wiki-Card Types](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Card_types)

> Curses are worth –1 VP at the end of the game, and are the only card type to consist of only one card name. All games of Dominion include Curses in the supply, though in many games Curses will never be gained or otherwise interacted with. They have purple frames. The number of Curses in a game is equal to ten times the number of players after the first - 10 Curses for a 2-player game, 20 for a 3-player game, and so forth.

Comment: I belive (though I could be wrong), that the wiki was referring to the curse _card_, as opposed to the curse _type_.

Comment: @MrHiTech Can you give an example of a curse type that is different?

Comment: There isn’t anything in _official_ dominion but maybe something like “cursed village” (I know that name is for a different card, it’s just an example) that is + 1 card, + 2 actions, and worth - 1 VP at the end of the game, cost $2. That would be an action-curse, and definitely be of the curse type, but it would certainly not be a “dead card”.

Comment: Of course that would only be if the definition of curse is “anything that gives - VP”, which is exactly my question.

Comment: Cursed Village is an Action-Doom card types

Comment: @MrHiTech I have updated my answer

Comment: I was talking about mine (we can call it hexed village) which is + 1 card, + 2 actions, and - 1 VP at the end of the game

Comment: And doom means it uses hexes

Comment: @MrHiTech No one will be able to answer any questions about your own cards. This answer is designed to answer what a curse card means in the current game of dominion and can't include any of the hundreds of homebrew expansions for the game. I would also say that just because a card gives negative victory points doesn't mean that it is a curse card as in the official game curse cards are something that provide the player no benefit at all.

Comment: But be prepared to argue some more if an expansion comes out with another card with the curse type 

Comment: Also you said “any questions”, but can I still ask game balance questions about my cards?

Comment: @MrHiTech Yes you can ask those types of questions but make sure you provide enough detail so people fully understand what you are doing with those cards and be careful about wording so it isn't an opinion or very broad answer wise.